# Checking for a limit and finding the sum of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

1) Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\frac{i}{2})^{2n}$

2) Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{1+2+3}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4+5}+......$

---

How do i go about finding the sum of the two series?

As I understand it, if the partial sums tend to a limit then that limit is the sum of the series. And if not then it has no sum?

Given that I guess that 2) equal 2 but I don't know how a proper argument could be made for that result.

Comment: What is the $i$ in the first series?

Comment: For the second series, note that $1+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so the second series is actually $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, which is a telescoping sum and the sum is $2$.

Comment: Recognise that the first sum is geometric. But geometric series converge only under certain conditions. What then can you say about which $i$ allow the series to converge?

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards 1), since $i^2=-1$, then
$$\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{2n}=\left(\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^2\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{i^2}{2^2}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n}.$$
Hence the partial sum of the first $N$ terms is
$$S_N=\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{2n}=
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n}
=\frac{-1}{4}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\\
=\frac{-1}{4}\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n}
=\frac{-1}{4}\cdot \frac{1-(-1/4)^{N}}{1-(-1/4)}=
\frac{-1+(-1/4)^{N}}{5}$$
where we used a basic property of the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Is the series convergent? 
What is the limit of the partial sum $S_N$ as $N\to\infty$?

For 2), as remarked by Frank Lu, note that $1+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and the partial sum is
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=2\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}-2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+1}\\=2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}-2\sum_{m=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{m}=2-\frac{2}{N+1}$$
We may now conclude that the limit of the partial sum $S_N$ as $N\to\infty$ is $2$.

Comment: I will have to look over 2) to understand the reasoning behind it what  you wrote.

regarding 1). I can check for converge with the ratio test. I believe it would equal 1/4 but I have to doublecheck. Am I right to understand that, as it converges to 1/4 that the sum is 1/4?

Comment: @Sirmimer The convergence is ok. But the sum is not $1/4$. Visit the link that I gave you!

Comment: @Sirmimer See my edited answer.

Comment: 1) $S_N$ as $N\to\infty$ it equals $\infty$ correct?
Also while trying to make sense of the geometric series and your notes I have to ask why you add $N-1$ before rewriting $i$ using the properties of $i^2=-1$. Is that an error?

Comment: No, the sum is convergent (you showed it by the ratio test) :
What is $\lim_{N\to+\infty}((-1/4)^N)$? 
In 1), $S_N$ is the sum of the first $N$ terms (from $0$ to $N-1$).

Comment: Aah... It converges to 0 and therefore the sum equal 0?

Comment: @Sirmimer It converges to 0 and therefore the sum is equal to $\frac{1}{1-(-1/4)}$...

Comment: @Sirmimer Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes. I am still trying to figure out how you rewrite the initial series, when adding the information that $i^2=-1$. As I understand you are rewriting the series such that you start at 0 and therefore have $N-1$. But It is a bit fuzzy to me. Are you doing multiple steps within the first equation sign or does the fact that $i^2=-1$ simply effect the series in that way?
Im really uncertain how you get the new expression for the series, simply based on the fact that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: As I understand it, you've round the ratio $r=(-1/4)$, but I don't quite get how

Comment: @Sirmimer See my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you! I believe I understand it now. Last thing though, just to confirm: As you "move a step back" you write n=0, and N-1?

Comment: @Sirmimer In your statement the first sum starts at $n=0$.No step back here.

Comment: I am terrible sorry, that is a typo. The problem I'm trying to solve is n=1

Comment: @Sirmimer Now I moved a step back and the final sum is $-1/5$. Any further doubt?

Comment: I think I understand it now. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Sorry I accidently "upvoted" instead of accepting the answer. I understand there's a queue of unanswered questions, so it's the least I can do now that you answered, plus more.